# Сумма классов js

Tags: javascript, классы, суммирование

Нужно получить сумму классов у которых `data-option` равны

```
<p class="sum" data-option="2018.04.02">100</p>
<p class="sum" data-option="2018.04.02">100</p>
<p class="sum" data-option="2018.04.03">200</p>
<p class="sum" data-option="2018.04.03">200</p>
```

Получить нужно массив

Comment: зачем было удалять предыдущий такой же вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант.

```
function func() {
    // берем все элементы с классом sum
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');
    var obj = {}
    // проходим по всем элементам
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var attribute = elements[i].getAttribute('data-option') // берем значение аттрибута
        var value = Number(elements[i].innerHTML) // берем значение и переводим в число
        // если такой ключ уже существует, то прибавляем к значению текущее значение
        if (obj[attribute]) { 
            obj[attribute] += value
        // если такого ключа нет, то создаем
        } else {
            obj[attribute] = value
        }
    }
    // берем только значения объекта
    var result = Object.values(obj)
}
```

Comment: Еще было бы не плохо если бы функция возвращала результат

Comment: Я не знаю как человек собирается манипулировать этими данными, поэтому дошел только до результата:)

Comment: Стоит добавить описание того, что в коде происходит